# C++ Strange behavior in my own stack class

Tags: c++, class, stack, destructor

Here is a program with my Stack class and some another functions.

- `ReadTheFile()` - reads numbers, which are stored in `num_file.txt`,    and returns a vector with those numbers.
- `IntervalCheck()` - adds    the numbers of the specific range from input vector and returns a    vector with those numbers only.
- `VecToMyStack()` - adds numbers from    a vector to a stack.

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  #include <fstream>
  #define STACK_EMPTY -1
  #define OUT_OF_STACK -2
  using namespace std;

  template <class T>
  class Stack {
  private:
      struct Node{
          T element;
          Node *prevElement;
      };
      size_t NumberOfElements;
      Node *tempAdr;
      Node *topElement;
      Node *newElement;
      Node *erasedElement;
  public:
      Stack(){
          topElement = new Node;
          topElement->prevElement = nullptr;
          NumberOfElements = 0;
      }

      ~Stack(){
          cout << endl << "I'm a destructor";
      while(NumberOfElements !=0 ){
          tempAdr = topElement->prevElement;
          delete topElement;
          topElement = tempAdr;
          NumberOfElements--;
      }
      delete topElement;
      }

      void push(T input_element){
          tempAdr = topElement;
          topElement = new Node;
          topElement->element = input_element;
          topElement->prevElement = tempAdr;
          NumberOfElements++;
      }

      void pop(){
          if (NumberOfElements == 0) throw STACK_EMPTY;
          else {
              tempAdr = topElement->prevElement;
              delete topElement;
              topElement = tempAdr;
              NumberOfElements--;
          }
      }

      T top(){
          return NumberOfElements != 0 ? topElement->element : throw STACK_EMPTY;
      }

      void insert(size_t position, T input_element){
          if (position >= NumberOfElements) throw OUT_OF_STACK;
          else {
              tempAdr = topElement;
              for (size_t i = 0; i < position; i++){
                  tempAdr = tempAdr->prevElement;
              }
              newElement = new Node;
              newElement->element = input_element;
              newElement->prevElement = tempAdr->prevElement;
              tempAdr->prevElement = newElement;
              NumberOfElements++;
          }
      }

      void erase(size_t position){
          if (position >= (NumberOfElements-1)) throw OUT_OF_STACK;
          else{
              tempAdr = topElement;
              for (size_t i = 0; i < position; i++){
                  tempAdr = tempAdr->prevElement;
              }
              erasedElement = tempAdr->prevElement;
              tempAdr->prevElement = tempAdr->prevElement->prevElement;
              delete erasedElement;
              NumberOfElements--;
          }
      }

      void print(){
          if (NumberOfElements != 0){
              tempAdr = topElement;
              for (size_t i = 0; i < NumberOfElements; i++){
                  cout << tempAdr->element << " ";
                  tempAdr = tempAdr->prevElement;
              }
          }
      }

      size_t size() { return NumberOfElements; }


  };


  vector<int> ReadTheFile() { 
      vector<int> vec_from_file;
      int buffer;
      ifstream basefile;
      basefile.open("num_file.txt", ios::in); 
      if (basefile.is_open()) {   
          do {
              if (basefile >> buffer) 
                  vec_from_file.push_back(buffer); 
              else { 
                  basefile.clear(); 
                  basefile.ignore(1, ' '); 
              }
          } while (!basefile.eof());  
          basefile.close();
      }
      else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
      return vec_from_file; 
  }


  vector<int> IntervalCheck(vector<int> vec_for_check){ 
      vector<int> out_vec;
      if (vec_for_check.empty()) cout << "There is nothing to check"; 
      else {
          int begin_int, end_int;
          do {
              cin.clear(); 
              cin.sync(); 
              cout << "Input the first and the last value of the interval: ";
              cin >> begin_int >> end_int;
          } while (cin.fail()); 
          for (auto &k : vec_for_check) 
              if (k > begin_int && k < end_int)
                  out_vec.push_back(k); 
      }
      return out_vec; 
  }


  Stack<int> VecToMyStack(vector<int> input_vec){
      Stack<int> output_st;
      if (input_vec.empty()) {
          cout << "the end";
      }
      else {
          for (auto &k : input_vec){
              output_st.push(k);
          }
      }
      return output_st;
  }

  int main(){

      int choice = 0;
      do {
          cin.clear();
          cin.sync();
          VecToMyStack(IntervalCheck(ReadTheFile())).print();
          cout << "Would you like to measure another interval? 1-yes 2-no";
          cin >> choice;
      } while (choice == 1);
      system("pause");
      return 0;
  }
  ```

The whole program should push numbers from the file to a stack, and print this stack, using the `print()` method of the class. For example, if there is a `num_file.txt` with

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

inside, the program is expected to work in that way:

- Input the first and the last value of the interval: 0 10 /* zero and
  ten are inputed by the user*/
- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- Would you like to measure another interval? 1-yes 2-no

But when the `VecToMyStack(IntervalCheck(ReadTheFile())).print();` line is executed, I'm getting

> *Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.*

exception. It seemes like the destructor of my Stack class is running before the `print()`function. Why does that happen? Is there something special what I should add to my Stack class or to `VecToMyStack()` function?

Comment: `0xFEEEFEEE` is a special value in the [MSVC debug heap implementation](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html). You're using something after it was deleted.

Comment: You really need to read about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: Probably a typo. The delete within the loop is `delete topElement;` but should be `delete tempAdr;`

Comment: Your `stack` class is fundamentally flawed and cannot work correctly until you implement a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.  You are returning `Stack` by value, and that cannot work correctly with the code you have.  (It's as if no one is taught the rule of 3, and only realize it when they come here or on other sites.  Is the state of teaching C++ this bad?)

Comment: Okay guys, it seems that I should actually follow the rule of three

Comment: Sorry for interrupting you guys, but can you please help me to make a proper copy constructor implementation? I've tried to make it myself, but it seems I'm stuck...Can you give me any ideas at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a couple of hours of research, I've got that missing peace of code:

```
Stack(const Stack &object){
        tempAdr = object.topElement;
        T * tempMas=new T[object.NumberOfElements];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < object.NumberOfElements; i++){
            tempMas[i] = tempAdr->element;
            tempAdr = tempAdr->prevElement;
        }
        topElement = new Node;
        topElement->prevElement = nullptr;
        NumberOfElements = 0;
        for (int i = object.NumberOfElements - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            push(tempMas[i]);
        }
        delete[] tempMas;
    }
```

I know that my Stack class is still uncomplete without the overloaded assignment operator, but at least my code runs fine.